# Trying to delete specific features within feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, cursor, error-000732

I am working with arcmap 10.2.

I have a database that has a few feature classes in it. Within these feature classes, they have a field labeled as Height. Height is a string field that houses numbers (i.e 54, 54 m, 54 meters).

```
env.workspace = folder + "\\Base_Intermediate_Data.gdb"
temp_fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for temp in temp_fc:

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(temp, temp + "_rural")

    if temp.endswith("Polygons_Rural"):

        heights_poly = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(temp, ["height", "OBJECTID"])

        for height in heights_poly:
            if height[0] != None:
                s = re.search(" ", height[0])
                if s:
                    f = height[0].find(" ")
                    if float(height[0][:f]) < 154:
                        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(temp + "_rural", "", """ OBJECTID = {0} """.format(height[1]))
                        arcpy.Delete_management(temp + "_rural")

                else:
                    if float(height[0]) < 154:
                        print "OBJ: ", height[1]
                        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(temp + "_rural", "", """ OBJECTID = {0} """.format(height[1]))
                        arcpy.Delete_management(temp + "_rural")
```

I am encountering this error:

ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset OSM_Polygons_Rural_rural does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

But, I am not sure why. And because of this error, I can't tell if I am correctly deleting the features that meet my criteria.

Comment: Try using [arcpy.Exists](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help./index.html#//000v00000021000000) to make sure the dataset exists (at a guess, you have mistakenly added "rural" to the featureclass name twice. You already know the name ends with "Polygons_Rural" but you are adding "_rural" again)

Comment: I am doing that to differentiate the feature layer from the feature class, but I will try the .exists. Thanks. Although, I know the feature class will exist and does exist, as  I am creating it prior in the script, I just have not referenced that here since I did not think it was needed.

Comment: You're trying to delete the *features* that satisfy the query aren't you? Delete_management doesn't do that.. it will clear out the layer so you can reuse the name or delete a feature class entirely; I think what you want is DeleteFeatures_management http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000036000000 which will remove the selected rows from the feature class. That's not what the error is though.. it's because you've deleted the layer on the first iteration therefore it doesn't exist to select by attributes again. Can you explain a bit more of what you want here pls.

Comment: I was unaware of the DeleteFeatures method. Allow me to attempt that and get back to you. Thanks.

Edit: Bingo! DeleteFeatures_management worked like a charm. Thanks again.